# How do you set GPG to use ElGamal and RSA for keys?

Tags: gnupg, rsa

How do you set GPG to use ElGamal and RSA for my GPG key? I'd like to do it but for the life of me I can't figure out what options to use.

Answer (score 0):

--gen-key
Generate a new key pair. This command is normally only used interactive.

--cipher-algo name
Use name as cipher algorithm. Running the program with the command --version yields a list of supported algorithms. If this is not used the cipher algorithm is selected from the preferences stored with the key.

Google is your friend....
http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.en.html

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new key RSA master key that is only capable of certifying or signing and certifying.  Then edit the key to add an RSA signing subkey.  Then add an encryption subkey and select El-Gamal instead of RSA.  It takes a few minutes longer (maybe more than a few, depending on the size of the keys), but it's worth it.

One of these days I'll get around to digging out my step-by-step instructions for the process and putting them somewhere useful.  Customisations like this are only really possible through the command line, but it's not that much of a chore.